# Do handlers postDelays not work with for loops I've tried several ways, but cant get it to work. Kotlin, android studios

Tags: loops, android-studio, kotlin, delay, handler

pls pardon the bad way I program at the moment, I'm very new to programming.

Okay, let's say I making a simple dnd dice roller(cause I am). I made it so it rolls a bunch of random numbers based on how many dice they want rolled and the type of dice. it then sends it to a text view, one at a time believe. I wanted to add a short delay, so I asked stackOverFlow, and got a handler working I believe; however, for the same reason I needed delay for in the first place. It only shows the last number rolled on the display with a now short delay between button presses. I would like show the user each number rolled one at a time with a short delay between each.

Example of the code without handler:

```
else if (numTimesRolled.progress <= 4) {
                for (i in 0 until numTimesRolled.progress + 1){
                    randNum = Random.nextInt(1, diceIsComfirm)
                    resultsArray[i] = randNum.toString()
                    randNumDisplay.text = resultsArray[i]
                }
            randNumResultsDisplay.text = "Rolled ${resultsArray.joinToString(" ")}"
        }
```

Outputs: the last number rolled

Examples of where I tried to use a handler:

```
else if (numTimesRolled.progress <= 3) {
            for (i in 0 until numTimesRolled.progress + 1){
                randNum = Random.nextInt(1, diceIsComfirm)
                resultsArray[i] = randNum.toString()
                    var runResults = Runnable {
                        randNumDisplay.text = resultsArray[i]
                    }
                var delayResults = Handler()
                delayResults.postDelayed(runResults, 1000)
            }
            //for (i in 0 until numTimesRolled.progress + 1){

            //}
            randNumResultsDisplay.text = "Rolled ${resultsArray.joinToString(" ")}"
        }
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
else if (numTimesRolled.progress <= 3) {
            for (i in 0 until numTimesRolled.progress + 1){
                randNum = Random.nextInt(1, diceIsComfirm)
                resultsArray[i] = randNum.toString()
            }
            for (i in 0 until numTimesRolled.progress + 1){
                var runResults = Runnable {
                    randNumDisplay.text = resultsArray[i]
                }
                var delayResults = Handler()
                delayResults.postDelayed(runResults, 1000)
            }
            randNumResultsDisplay.text = "Rolled ${resultsArray.joinToString(" ")}"
        }
```

Output: both run as normally, but with a delay on the last numbers of the many rolled for each time the button is pressed.

I tried making the whole for loop as the "Runnable," but that was just me being stupid looking for solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostDelay doesn't wait for the amount of time.  It posts a message to a handler specifying when it should do something.  To get what you want, each postDelay runnable has to post another post delay.

Comment: I see, do you know of a way that could work in the way I'm doing it rn? Do I have to learn about co routines, or is there something easier?

Comment: The easiest way?  PostDelay each message for i*1000.  That will post 10 runnables, each of which will run at different delays.  You don't need to learn about coroutines to do this, although they provide another easy way to do it (have the coroutine run on the main thread, and have it delay 1000 there.  The delay will sleep, allowing other code to run on the main thread so it isn't blocked).

Comment: Oh ok that makes sense with "i*1000" I think (I'll have to just do it to find out if I understood), and the coroutine was one of the options suggested to me; however it was a little too complicated for me since I'm pretty new. Thanks for your help and insight, much appreciated.